# Configuring Https for play 2.4 in production: Unable to find HTTPS keystore

Tags: scala, ssl, https, playframework

## BACKGROUND

I am using **play 2.4** with scala. I am trying to enable **Https** for play. I have generated a keystore `test.jks` and placed it inside `/conf` of my play application. And I have following settings inside `application.conf`:

```
play.crypto.secret= "my application secret"
play.server.https.keyStore.path = "conf/test.jks"
play.server.https.keyStore.type = "JKS"
play.server.https.keyStore.password = "my keystore password"
```

Then, when I start my application using following command, https is successfully enabled:

```
sbt "start -Dhttps.port=9001"
```

That means, I can now access `https://localhost:9001` and also access `http://localhost:9000`.

## PROBLEM

For my requirement, I am using [sbt dist](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#Using-the-dist-task) to deploy my application. As we know, `dist` produces a ZIP file containing all JAR files and also a `script` needed to run the application in the target/universal folder of our application.

So, I am trying to enable `https` while using the generated `script` from `dist task` as follow:

```
bin/my-app -Dconfig.resource=application.conf -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dhttps.port=9001
```

Now,I can access my app at `http://localhost:9000` but I can't access `https://localhost:9001`. Below is the contents of my application log:

```
[[37minfo[0m] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[[37minfo[0m] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTPS on port /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9001
[[31merror[0m] p.c.s.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory - cannot load SSL context
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:96) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to find HTTPS keystore at "/my_path_to_project/target/universal/my-app-1.0/my-app/conf/test.jks"
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:53) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:21) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
[[31merror[0m] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
[[31merror[0m] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
```

The funny thing from above log is this part: `Unable to find HTTPS keystore at "/my_path_to_project/target/universal/my-app-1.0/my-app/conf/test.jks"`

But, when I checked, I do have test.jks created inside `/target/universal/my-app-1.0/my-app/conf/`.

## QUESTION

Why is play unable to find HTTPS keystore(`test.jks`) while using `sbt dist`?

Comment: So do you have your keystore in /my_path_to_project/target/universal/my-app-1.0/my-app/conf/test.jks or in /target/universal/my-app-1.0/my-app/conf/ ?

Comment: Yes, the `keystore` is there.

Comment: What is output of "ls -al /my_path_to_project/target/universal/my-app-1.0/my-app/conf/‌​test.jks"? A reason why I'm so scrupulous about it is because your exception is very specific regarding reason why it is thrown.

Comment: Yes, but there is `test.jks` in that location. I think I have already made that clear in the question.

Comment: I see, but the reason I'm asking for output of "ls" command is to see more details (e.g. permissions of the file, type of file etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for production using `dist`

Put your jks file in `/home/ubuntu/` folder and try giving absolute path `/home/ubuntu/test.jks` in application.conf.

Note: edit application.conf file from `/path/to/application/target/universal/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/conf/application.conf`

Comment: Thank you. Turns out absolute path is required.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

Steps to reproduce:

### Key store generation

```
keytool -genkey -alias MyKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore conf/store.jks
```

(then during interactive Q/A session use the same password for store and key, e.g. "blablastore")

### application.conf

```
play.crypto.secret= "just secret"
play.server.https.keyStore.path = "conf/store.jks"
play.server.https.keyStore.type = "JKS"
play.server.https.keyStore.password = "blablastore"
```

### Deployment

```
sbt dist
cd target/universal/
unzip *.zip
cd <project-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT>
```

### Running

```
bin/<project-name> -Dconfig.resource=application.conf -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dhttps.port=9001
```

Comment: Actually,  I had followed the same process. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @oblivion have you discovered how to fix this problem? I just followed all the suggestions and it didn't work for me neither :(

Comment: @DouglasKaminski I used `sbt stage` command instead of `dist` and it worked for me. For more info, see : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#Running-a-production-server-in-place

Comment: That is not quite the answer to the question but that is what I used and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use config.resource, it means that Play will look for the files in the resource JAR. That also implies that your keystore needs to be inside the jar.

You need to check if that is the case.